# Update div when typing in text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to update a div while changing the value of a input field.

Eg.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="test"><!--Eg. 5+5-->
</form>

<div id="SomeId">
<img src=loading.gif>
</div>
```

So when you changed the value of the input field, it updated the div SomeId, with a external file Eg. calculate.php?test=5+5

So how can I listen on updating a input field?

Comment: bind input text with keyup or key down event i.e., `$('#INPUT_TXT_ID').on('keyup', function(){ console.log($(this).val())})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input type="text" onkeypress="doSomething(this.value);">` will send the entire value of the input element to the function after every key press.

Note that best practice is to bind the function on page load using JavaScript, and not with `onkeypress` but doing the latter gives a one-line example.

Here's a `doSomething` function for testing:

```
function doSomething(what) {
    console.log(what);
}
```

Edited to add: If you don't want to process every keystroke, use the `onchange` event:
`<input type="text" onchange="doSomething(this.value);">`

Another edit:

```
var timerHandle = false; // global!
function setTimer(what) {
    console.log("Captured keys: " + what);
    if (timerHandle) clearTimeout(timerHandle);
    timerHandle = setTimeout(sendItOff,1000); // delay is in milliseconds
}
function sendItOff() {
    what = document.getElementById("test").value;
    console.log("Sending " + what);
}
```

The input element now has to have an ID:
`<input type="text" name="test" id="test" onkeypress="setTimer(this.value);">`

This uses a one second (1000 ms) timer.  That is *very* short.

Comment: Dosen't work. Heres what it output if I type 12345. 

    ""
    "1"
    "12"
    "123"
    "1234"

Comment: Yes, it's calling the function after every character.  If you don't want to process every keystroke, use the `onchange` event:

`<input type="text" onchange="doSomething(this.value);">`

Comment: Then I have to click to make it update. Is it possible to do it without clicking?

Comment: If you don't process every keystroke, and even if you do, the user has to indicate "done" somehow.  Tabbing out of the field, clicking elsewhere, or pressing "enter" will all to that.  (Note that pressing "enter" will also submit the form by default.  You may need an `onsubmit="return false;"` to prevent that.)

So, decide what the user must do to indicate "done" and put some instructions or edit your question.

Comment: Isn't it possible in some way to make it change if the user haven't changed the value in more than 1 second?

Comment: Sure.  Go back to capturing each keystroke.  Start a `setTimeout` on the first keystroke and save the handle it returns.  (You can do that with a closure, but it may be easiest to understand of you use a global variable.)  On each subsequent keystroke, clear and restart the timer.  If `setTimeout` runs to completion without being cleared by a keystroke, it should run the function that submits the data.

Note that you deprive the user of "think time" if you do this, so be sure you really want to do it.

Comment: Try replacing `onkeypress` with `onkeyup` if you want the text to update without having to click elsewhere or pressing "enter".

Answer (score 0):

In the focusout of the text field, Call java script function that should call ajax call to that calculate.php.
    Return response from php file and update that in particular div Id.

```
function onfocusoutupdatevalue(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "calculate.php",
  data: { value: "5+5" }
  }).done(function( ans ) {
    $("#SomeId").val(ans) 
  });
}
```

You need to add jQuery lib file.